# rails rendering collection not working - undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a feed that displays all comments for a model.

**_comments.html.erb**

```
<% if @comments.any? %>
    <ol>
      <%= render partial: 'shared/comment_feed', collection: @comments %>
    </ol>
    <%= will_paginate @comments %>
<% else %>
    <h2>Be the first one to comment on this episode!</h2>
<% end %>
```

**_comment_feed.html.erb**

```
<li id="<%= comment.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(comment.user), comment.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="content"><%= simple_format comment.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
  <% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
    <%= link_to "delete", comment, method: :delete,
                                   confirm: "Are you sure?",
                                   title: comment.content %>
  <% end %> 
</li>
```

The above code gives me an ***undefined local variable or method `comment'*** error. Doesn't rails automatically generate comment when a partial is used to render comments collections? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the local variable corresponds to the name of the partial. In your case the local variable is going to be named `comment_feed`.